# How to validate data in Meteor.methods()

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor.methods() to insert data into MongoDB, since I never trust client side: how can I validate data (form input) server side?

What is the best way/practice to do this? Hints, tips?

Example

```js
Meteor.methods({
    addPlayer: function(formInput) {

        // Validation: if not valid I will throw a Meteor.Error.

        var playerId = Players.insert({name: formInput.playerName});

        return playerId;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor has package `Match` for js validation.

[Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#match)

```
Meteor.methods({addChat: function (roomId, message) {
  check(roomId, String);
  check(message, {
    text: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    // Optional, but if present must be an array of strings.
    tags: Match.Optional([String])
  });
```

Comment: How can I change the text of the Error and return the Error to the` Meteor.call('addPlayer', playerName.value, function(error, result) {`? from the Meteor.methods()?

Comment: @MassimilianoMarini, what would be the point of doing that? You should validate (and display errors) on the client before the client calls the method (so the server doesn't need to tell the client what's wrong).

Comment: @PeppeL-G I was thinking to delegate the task of validation to the server and the task to display the error message if any to the client. But actually this does not make much sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Peppe L-G not all validation rules can be checked on the client, for example the verification that the email address not busy other user.

Comment: @xhr, of course you're right (my comment was regarding the `check` function).